# Lan Driver for Gigabyte g41m combo driver

Tags: drivers

Linux driver not in Cd of gigabyte g41m combo mother board. Need driver and installation instructions.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu? 12.04 seems to have support for gigabyte g41m out of the box. If <12.04 and you have an Atheros try this: http://tuxthink.blogspot.nl/2010/08/enabling-atheros-ethernet-controller-on.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with me. G41M combo motherboard. I am running ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.
Simplest solution I have found is.

1. Download compat wireless drivers from here.
   http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.bz2
2. Extract the archive to some location.
3. Open your terminal and go into above extracted location.
4. Run `sudo make` . It will copy all required drivers for e.g `atl1e` `atl1c` etc.

Done! Check if your internet is working now.
Cheers!